# What are odd radio circles (ORCs) in Space?

Tags: astrophysics, radio-frequency

There is a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jXnXbMcI8Lo&t=595s) about pure radio waves radiating in circles in space. [Odd radio circles (ORCs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_radio_circle) are not radiating any other wave length (visible light, x-ray or gamma ray)

Do we know anything other than what is in the video?

Answer (score 0):

The video covers most of what is known about these objects. There is not much known. The Wikipedia page has one short paragraph discussing these objects.  The source given [here](https://www.space.com/ghostly-circles-puzzle-astronomers) has a page describing these objects but claims no one knows what they are. The article lists a collection of objects they aren't which could be helpful.  Several of these objects have been found.